Changing registry key from Endpoint Manager (Intune)
I've been trying several things to roll out this registry key change from Intune. I'm now trying to use the remediation process to do so.
I used this tool to create the scripts: https://reg2ps.azurewebsites.net/
The following are my scripts and settings:
Detection Script:
try {
    if(-NOT (Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24")){ return $false };
    if(-NOT (Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services")){ return $false };
    if(-NOT (Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax")){ return $false };
    if(-NOT (Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\PDF")){ return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'LogoClickUrl' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'https://creator.pdf24.org/logoClick.php') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'Label' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'pdf24') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'CreatorID' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'pdf24') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'CreatorName' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'pdf24.org') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'CreatorEmail' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'team@pdf24.org') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'Installer' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'innoSetup') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'InstallationID' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'D0DF8C8C-74FD-4B73-9411-B9C45C7A8481') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'InstallDir' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'C:\Program Files\PDF24') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'UpdateMode' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 2) {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax' -Name 'Port' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq '\\.\pipe\FaxPrint') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax' -Name 'Handler' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'shellCmd') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax' -Name 'ShellCmd' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq '"%binDir%\pdf24-Fax.exe"') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax' -Name 'RequestUrl' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'https://faxout.pdf24.org') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\PDF' -Name 'Port' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq '\\.\pipe\PDFPrint') {  } else { return $false };
    if((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\PDF' -Name 'Handler' -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq 'default') {  } else { return $false };
}
catch { return $false }
return $true

Remediation Script:
if((Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24") -ne $true) {  New-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24" -force -ea SilentlyContinue };
if((Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services") -ne $true) {  New-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services" -force -ea SilentlyContinue };
if((Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax") -ne $true) {  New-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax" -force -ea SilentlyContinue };
if((Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\PDF") -ne $true) {  New-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\PDF" -force -ea SilentlyContinue };
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'LogoClickUrl' -Value 'https://creator.pdf24.org/logoClick.php' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'Label' -Value 'pdf24' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'CreatorID' -Value 'pdf24' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'CreatorName' -Value 'pdf24.org' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'CreatorEmail' -Value 'team@pdf24.org' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'Installer' -Value 'innoSetup' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'InstallationID' -Value 'D0DF8C8C-74FD-4B73-9411-B9C45C7A8481' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'InstallDir' -Value 'C:\Program Files\PDF24' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24' -Name 'UpdateMode' -Value 2 -PropertyType DWord -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax' -Name 'Port' -Value '\\.\pipe\FaxPrint' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax' -Name 'Handler' -Value 'shellCmd' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax' -Name 'ShellCmd' -Value '"%binDir%\pdf24-Fax.exe"' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\Fax' -Name 'RequestUrl' -Value 'https://faxout.pdf24.org' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\PDF' -Name 'Port' -Value '\\.\pipe\PDFPrint' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\PDF24\Services\PDF' -Name 'Handler' -Value 'default' -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;

Settings
I now tried to run the remediation on the device but it doesn't change the registry key value from 1 to 2. Nothing happens.

in intune, did you set "Run script in 64-bit PowerShell" to "Yes" ? If you did not, you should find your keys in "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\PDF24 on the remediated computer

I tried both. I started with it running on 64-bit, then when it didn't work I tried it with the option disabled. The registry location you've suggested doesn't exist, so no key either.
